# django - how do i make a drop down field that is tied to the database?

Tags: django

i just  want a dropdown field - kind like below:

```
Sex: | Male   |v|
     | Female |
```

you know, a very very standard drop down.

I've created this to that  end:

```
class Relationship(models.Model):

    SEX = [
        ("M","Male"),
        ("F","Female")
    ]

    title =  models.CharField(max_length=100)

    sex = models.ChoiceField(label='', choices=SEX)
```

i will handle the label in the template on my own, hence the `label=""`

The problem is this: when i run syncdb, django freaks out, because below all this is:

```
class RelationshipForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Relationship
        ordering = ['create_date']
        fields = ('title','sex')
```

Sadly, this causes me to get this exception:

> django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (sex) specified for Relationship

What the heck am i meant to do? To be clear:

1. i want the relationship database table created to have a "sex" field that holds, well, either Male or Female
2. i want the wee dropdown to show up when you make a new relationship.

I'm sure this is super simple, any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There is no `ChoiceField` in models. You want `CharField` with choices as below.

`sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, label='', choices=SEX)`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
class Profile(models.Modell):
    """
    User profile model
    """
    PROF = 1
    DR = 2
    MR = 3
    MRS = 4
    MS = 5
    PROFESSION_TITLE = ((PROF, 'Prof.'),
                        (DR, 'Dr.'),
                        (MR, 'Mr'),
                        (MRS, 'Mrs'),
                        (MS, 'Ms'),)
    # personal details
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    title = models.IntegerField('Title', choices=PROFESSION_TITLE,
            max_length=25, blank=True, null=True)
```

See this link: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/02/handle-choices-right-way/

Answer (score 0):

Argh. I see what i was doing wrong - elementary mistake. I'll keep this up here for now, unless everyone here thinks that this is the sort of elementary thing that is unnecessary @ SO

In the Model:

```
class Relationship(models.Model):

    title =  models.CharField(max_length=100)

    sex = models.CharFieldField(max_length=100)
```

in the Form:

```
class RelationshipForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Relationship
        ordering = ['create_date']
        fields = ('title','sexField')

    SEX = [
        ("M","guy"),
        ("F","girl")
    ]

    sexField = ChoiceField(label='', choices=SEX)

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(RelationshipForm, self).clean()
        self.instance.sex = (self.cleaned_data.get('sexField',None) )
```